# gnuplot reports empty x range with a range of dates

Tags: gnuplot

Given this file of data:

```
#date   foo bar
2018-10-12_11-54-52 12 1 
2018-10-12_11-55-09 14 7 
2018-10-12_11-55-16 13 10 
2018-10-12_13-00-01 15 8 
2018-10-12_14-00-01 12 9
```

and this set of plot commands:

```
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"
set xrange ["2018-10-12_11-54-52" : "2018-10-12_14-00-01"]
plot 'datafile.txt' using 1:2 with linespoints linestyle 1
plot 'datafile.txt' using 1:3 with linespoints linestyle 1
```

when I run gnuplot with `gnuplot -p cmd_file.txt` it errors with

```
line 3: Can't plot with an empty x range!
```

The xrange should be over 125 minutes long. Why does gnuplot think it is empty?

Comment: Add `set xdata time` prior to `set timefmt...`

Comment: Perfect, that is the reason. If you make it an answer I'll accept.